# error: identifier "ostream" is not defined

Tags: c++, g++, undefined, undefined-reference, ostream

Firstly, I have looked all over for solutions and I can't seem to fix it. When trying to compile source code I get the following error.

> g++ -c -I/home/jcallahan/ACM/include/FANSI -I/home/jcallahan/ACM/FourtyTwo/Base -I/home/jcallahan/ACM/FourtyTwo/FunctionSpaces -I/home/jcallahan/ACM/FourtyTwo/MeshLib   LagrangeFunctions.cpp
>   In file included from /home/jcallahan/ACM/include/FANSI/MatrixVector.h:6:0,
>                    from LagrangeFunctions.cpp:17:
>   /home/jcallahan/ACM/include/FANSI/Matrix.h:184:24: **error: ‘ostream’ has not been declared
>      void WriteToTextFile(ostream &) ;**

The error is coming from the included **Matrix.h** and **Vector.h** (I have more of these errors only showing one). I believe the error is within **Matrix.h/Vector.h**. The code is cut off because I do not think that the classes member functions have anything to do with it.

```
#include "AbstractMatrix.h"

class Matrix : public AbstractMatrix
{
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &,const Matrix &) ;
  friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Matrix &) ;
 public:
```

Anyone have any clue what is going on or how I can fix it? For additional info I am using the g++ compiler.

Comment: add `#include <iostream>` to the top of your file

Comment: It seems that one of your headers uses `ostream` without qualification (`std::`) and without a suitable `using` declaration or `using` directive. Independent of the qualification a suitable header (`<iosfwd>` or `<ostream>`) may also be missing.

Comment: Mgetz,
I added in the include and it didn't change anything.

Dietmar,
I do not have a "using namespace std" in any of my headers but only this one gives me a problem. Also when compiling using PGI compilers it compiles without an issue

Comment: @user2584732: the error message quoted by thecompiler is certainly missing `std::`. Based on what you posted other things may be missing, too.

Comment: The class member function code is *clearly* something to do with it: the line that is the problem is the line given in the error message, which is the declaration of method `void WriteToTextFile(ostream &)`. *Read your error message* before posting. It should be `void WriteToTextFile(std::ostream &)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the duplicate here. That one was (only) about not qualifying the namespace in which the symbol resides. This one is (also) about simply not including the declaration of the symbol in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you posted should include this line:

```
#include <iostream>
```

---

Also, the error message includes this definition:

```
void WriteToTextFile(ostream &) ;
```

That needs to be changed to `std::ostream` like the others.

Comment: In the header file? I thought it was a no-no to put them in header files?

Comment: You probably confused the no-no with `using namespace std;`, which _is_ a no-no to put in header files.

Comment: It's not a no-no. One of the declarations uses `std::ostream`, so it’s pretty essential to include it.

Comment: I added in the #include <iostream> to the header file and it didn't change the error.

Comment: You added it above this definition, right? Which is line 184 of `Matrix.h`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed something the first time: The error message includes the problematic definition: `void WriteToTextFile(ostream &) ;`. That should be `std::ostream`. EDIT: updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I added it on line 42.

Comment: That fixed it Sidnicious. Any way to apply that without having to add it before it for every function?

Comment: I am just being lazy. I will just use emacs to find and replace all. Thank you everyone

Comment: Nice! In header files, you do usually use full names. But, in the header file or in your class definition you could use `using std::ostream;` to bring it into your namespace.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Teaching myself c++ and was hung up on this for a week trying to figure it out myself.